# How do you find the values of a that will cause a period-doubling bifurcation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Given the finite difference equation $x_{n+1}=ax_{n}exp(-x_{n})$ for $x_{n}\geq0$, where a is a positive constant. I've determined the fixed points to be $x^*=ln(a),0$. How do I determine the values of a that will give me a period doubling bifurcation?

Comment: Generally, $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ has a period-doubling bifurcation at a fixed point $a$ if $f'(x)$ goes through $-1$ as $x$ goes through $a$.

Comment: why is it the case when $f'(x)$ goes through -1 and not 1 that we have a period-doubling bifurcation?

Comment: There are other kinds of bifurcation you get as you go through 1 (tangent node, pitchfork, etc.). It helps if you draw a picture of a typical example.

Comment: ok, so i've determined that $f'(x)=-1$ when $a=e^{2}$. would that be correct?

Comment: Looks OK. So, test it to see whether you get period-doubling there.

Comment: How would you test for a period doubling?

Comment: You take a value of the parameter near the bifurcation point, where there's no fixed point, iterate the function, and see whether you get a point of period 2.